# Most efficient way to check if all given n objects are the same or distinct?

Tags: java, loops, oop, equals

Say if there are two Strings or any Objects and I want to check if both the objects are the same, I would do `string1.equals(string2)` and thats fine. Now if there are three objects and I want to see if they are all equal I would do `string1.equals(string2) && string2.equals(string3)` and say four and so on, that would only be possible if the size of the parameters are given. If I pass a n objects to a method, what would be the most efficient way to check if all the elements are equal or not. I wrote

```
private static boolean equals(Object... objects) {
    Object obj = objects[0];
    boolean flag = false;
    for (Object object : objects) {
        if (object.equals(obj)) {
            flag = true;
        } else {
            flag = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    return flag;
}
```

but when I showed this to professional programmers they pointed out that it is a really inefficient way to do it. If I want to check if all the elements are unique instead, how would that work?
Is there any efficient and concise method to check any n number of elements for equality or distinctness?

Comment: The only inefficiencies I see are one extra comparison and that `flag` isn't needed - each iteration has an unnecessary variable assignment.  But that inefficiency probably isn't measurable unless `objects` is large (and that's just a guess).

Comment: Andrew W is correct. The `Set` answers are false, given, that the objective is an efficient implementation.

Comment: the only way to find out is to measure, everything else is pure guessing when `jvm` is involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the `Set` interface. If you aren't familiar with Sets yet, quoting [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html)

> A Set is a Collection that cannot contain duplicate elements. It models the mathematical set abstraction. The Set interface contains only methods inherited from Collection and adds the restriction that duplicate elements are prohibited. Set also adds a stronger contract on the behavior of the equals and hashCode operations, allowing Set instances to be compared meaningfully even if their implementation types differ. Two Set instances are equal if they contain the same elements.

As a Set cannot contain duplicate elements, the size of the Set would always be one unless a distinct element is added to it or in other words the size of the Set would never be equal to the size of the elements passed unless they are all unique.
In your case it would be

```java
private static boolean equals(Object... obj) {
   Set<Object> set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(obj));
   return set.size() == 1; // Size of the Set should be one if all elements are same.
}
```

If you want you to check if all the elements are unique, you would check if the size of the `Set` and the size of the elements passed are the same instead.

Comment: Sets are not faster than a raw implementation. equality over n is O(n), while insertion of n elements is O(n*log(n))

Comment: I'm gonna go with this; It seems short but really concise and descriptive to me. Thanks.

Comment: Hm, yeah but this is a quite viable solution to the problem as well I suppose. :p

Comment: @AkshitSinha. Nope it's not the same. If you only assert that the set size is different from the array size, you only know, that at least two elements where the same, but *not* that all elements where the same.

Comment: @TreffnonX Thats what I'm saying. If all the elements are the same, the size of the set would never be equal to the size of the arguments. They would only be the same when all the elements are unique. Are there any edge case which does not follow as an example?

Comment: @AkshitSinha I think the problem is, that OP asked a double-question. On the one hand he asked, if all elements are equal, on the other, if *all* are distinct. The question is bad. I went for the first part, you went for the second... Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation is actually not that inefficient. It does some redundant comparisons, but overall the problem is linear. No matter the implementation, the algorithm is within O(n), which means, it scales linear. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation for details on the O-notation.

To prove that all elements in your array are equal, you have to disprove, that there is at least one element, non-equal to one other. So you correctly assumed, that the first encounter of an unmatch is enough to cancel the loop. The only issue with your implementation is, that you keep the first element, and then loop over all elements (including the first), which is 1 comparison more that required.

However the main issue is not efficiency, but `null`-safety. If your first object is `null` you effectively call `null.equals...` which raises a `NullPointerException`. Instead, the (probably) expected behavior would be to return `false`.

Therefore:

```
private static boolean equals(Object... objects) {
    Object first = objects[0];
    if (first == null) {
         for (int i = 1; i < objects.length; ++i) {
             if (objects[i] != null) {
                 return false;
             }
         }
    } else {
        for (int i = 1; i < objects.length; ++i) {
            Object other = objects[i];
            if (other == null || !first.equals(other)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know if it is more efficient, but it is very much less code to just put all the values into a `Set` and compare the amounts:

```
public static boolean areAllEqual(String ... words) {
    // put all the objects into a Set, which doesn't allow duplicates
    Set<String> setOfWords = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(words));

    // then compare the size of the Set to the length of the input array
    if (setOfWords.size() == words.length) {
        // and if those are equal, you have distinct values
        return true;
    } else {
        // otherwise there are at least two equal objects in the input array
        return false;
    }
}
```

I checked it the following way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(areAllEqual("equal", "equal", "equal", "equal", "equal", "equal", "equal"));
    System.out.println(areAllEqual("equal", "", "", "equal", "equal", "equal", "equal"));
    System.out.println(areAllEqual("equal", "", "", "", "", "", ""));
    System.out.println(areAllEqual("d", "i", "s", "t", "in", "ct", "values"));
}
```

which produces the output

```
false
false
false
true
```

Comment: While this is true, it is way less efficient, and scales badly. However, since it's a var-arg call, it might not matter.

Comment: @TreffnonX OK, good to know... An interesting fact is that the accepted answer is basically equal to mine, but uses even less lines of code ;-)